# How can I open a port in linux [UBUNTU] for all ip addresses?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, port-forwarding

I am trying to forward a remote port from my server to my development machine. I have tried opening the port via iptables, but it is open only for 127.0.0.1.

If I login to the server using ssh and try `curl http:127.0.0.1:FORWARDED PORT`, the request is redirected to my local development machine. But the port is inaccessible to outside ip addresses.

Here is the output of `netstat -an`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 **127.0.0.1:8099**          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 173.45.231.60:22        203.92.35.107:51994     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8099                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the optional bind_address to `*` E.g. if you're doing a local forward originating on the server (`-L`) then use `ssh -L '*:8099:localhost:8099' mydevbox` (note the quotes to keep the shell from expanding the asterisk)

Comment: I am doing a remote port forwarding. If my dev machine is accessible from outside, then I do not need this port forwarding stuff.

Comment: What are you using to do the port forward that works from localhost?

Comment: ssh -R 8099:localhost:3000 MY_REMOTE_SERVER

Comment: Then do the equivalent for the -R option... `-R *:8099:localhost:3000` Did you read the man page for the options you're using?

Comment: This sets a remote port forwarding from my server [8099 port] to local machine [3000]. The opened port [8099] listens only to local ip [127.0.0.1]. This means that if I make a local request on server to port 8099, it will be forwarded to my dev machine on port 3000. But if try to make a request from outside [server-ip:8099], it says server is inaccessible, since the bind address is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Ben I already did it. Of no use.

Comment: You might need to turn on GatewayPorts on the server. By default it ignores bind_address in remote forwards.

Comment: @Ben Bingo... that worked!!!!